# Matrix Algebra in regression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to if these two regression predictrion equations are equivalent:
The input and data is as follows

Let $\mathbf{x}_i=[\mathbf{x}^1_i, ..., \mathbf{x}^p_i]^t$, $\mathbf y$ be of dimension $n \times 1$ and $X$ be $p \times n$ such that

$$X=\begin{bmatrix} 
\mathbf{x_1}   & \mathbf{x_2} & ... &  \mathbf{x_n}
\end{bmatrix}$$

How is it true that

$$\mathbf{x}^t_{\ast}(XX^t+\sigma^2 I_p)^{-1}X\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x}_{\ast}^tX(X^tX+\sigma^2I_n)^{-1} \mathbf{y}$$

Note $I_p$ is a $p\times$ identity matrix, similarly for $I_n$ and $\mathbf{x}_{\ast}$ is any new input point.

Answer (score 0):

By [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity), we have
\begin{align}
& (XX^t + \sigma^2 I_p)^{-1} \\
= & \sigma^{-2}I_p - \sigma^{-2}X(I_n + \sigma^{-2}X^tX)^{-1}X^t\sigma^{-2}.
\end{align}

Therefore, 
\begin{align}
& x_*^t(XX^t + \sigma^2 I_p)^{-1}Xy \\
= & \sigma^{-2}x_*^tXy - \sigma^{-4}x_*^tX(I_n + \sigma^{-2}X^tX)^{-1}X^tXy \\
= & \sigma^{-2}x_*^tX(I_n - \sigma^{-2}(I_n + \sigma^{-2}X^tX)^{-1}X^tX)y
\tag{1}
\end{align}

Now set $A = I_n, U = \sigma^{-2}I_n, V = X^tX, C = I_n$ in the Woodbury identity to get
$$I_n - \sigma^{-2}(I_n + \sigma^{-2}X^tX)^{-1}X^tX =
(I_n + \sigma^{-2}X^tX)^{-1}. \tag{2}$$

The result then follows by substituting $(2)$ to $(1)$.